# How insert multiple values (list) to database via mysql python

Tags: python, mysql

I use mysql.connector to connect to database in Python. I can create query that insert values into database e.g

`sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("John", "Highway 21")
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
mydb.commit()`

but I wonder how can I do the same with list (list is dynamic so sometimes it looks like this: [val1, val2, val3] and other time can looks like this [val1, val2, val3, val4, ... val55]. I have prepared query:

`INSERT INTO tablename ("+', '.join(dataset.columns.tolist())+") VALUES (%s, %s)"`  but the question is how to deal with parameter %s in VALUES because sometimes as I said it can be 4 and other time 55. My only idea so far is to create string in loop and add as many %s parameters as need.

Comment: Are you aware of existence of [executemany](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html)?

Comment: Yes but I still have to pass parameter %s 
    sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
    mycursor.executemany(sql, val)

Comment: `executemany` do exactly what you need. Can you show your python code?

Comment: I got problem with %s parameter in VALUES. If I am correct this parameter tells how many arguments you will pass into insert statement. The problem is I do not know exactly how many I will pass. Sometimes It can be 4 sometimes 55 so I can not write query with VALUES(%s, %s) because It tells that I will pass only two arguments (I need to be flexible and I do not know how can I achieve that

Here is my code
sql = "INSERT INTO tableone("+', '.join(data.columns.tolist())+") VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
mycursor.executemany(sql, data.values.tolist())

Comment: Take your time and read [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html). If you still have problems - prepare an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating your problem

Comment: ok so my question for you is how would you create query from documentation which you linked when you had to write 4 values instead of two ('first_name', 'hire_date')
Would you write in values (%s, %s, %s ,%s) parameters instead of two?

Comment: Oh, I see! Please excuse me for my inattention.  You need not only concatenate values but field names too. So indeed your query becames truly dynamic. Check my answer a little later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your SQL-query needs to be truly dynamic (one step further and you step into area of ORMs and SQL-toolkits) I suppose you need something like

```
def gen_sql(fields, values):
     return f'INSERT INTO customers  ({",".join(fields)}) VALUES ({",".join(map(str,values))})'

print(gen_sql('name address'.split(), "'Johh' 'New-York'".split()))
print(gen_sql('a b c '.split(), (1,2,3)))
```

But "Here be dragons!":

- Quote-escaping is on responsibility of caller
- no prevention of sql-injection

Comment: Ok works fine for strings but is it possible to pass to VALUES list?

Comment: Look at `print`s in my code - the first example is passing list ["'Johh'", "'New-York'"]

Comment: And second example is tuple of `int`s

Comment: Oh I am sorry I have used split on list (which ofc does not work). Man you are great! Thank you for your help

Comment: Code generation is one task that I do frequently in python. But again: Beware! Here be dragons!

Comment: Last one question: how to execute your prepared statement. I got errors when I try to execute one of the three statements: [link](https://pastebin.com/LjE7r7sn)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188545/discussion-between-alex-yu-and-mr-lukas).